# how to pass a service method reference to forRoot config in ngModule decorator?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm new to angular and a bit confused with the DI thing

I'm working on a set of reusable component (aka library) packed under it's own module and featuring a common config thru the forRoot technique

```
imports: [
    MyModule.forRoot({
      color: "#00ff00",
      getDetail: ?????
    })
```

it works great for the static variables, but I would also like to pass a reference of the function retrieving data. This function is part of MyService.
I can use service method in component, when injected into the constructor.. but no idea how to pass this in the config in NgModule decorator

I hope I missed something and is easy to do. Or if not possible this way please suggest a intended solution.